# Delusion,fear and panic and shame

Tags: personal-experience

After facing death,I passed through a period of more than six months in delusion,fear and panic associated with shame.I was very much frightened and the experience was horrifying .After so many years my personality has completely changed,I don't know for better or for worse Although I have been occupying the Same body for 64 years.How to describe different stages and passing through different states In my mortal life? can it be termed as different rebirths(any kind of) for an ordinary man In Buddhist terms.May I add that Before twenty years I took a CANCER CAPSULE and went into deep and continuous sleep without interruption for 4/5 months, I woke up for one day and went into deep undisturbed and uninterrupted sleep for another three months. finally I woke up as a normal man.I could not come to a conclusion how to describe such experience.

Comment: **can it be termed as different rebirths(any kind of) for an ordinary man In Buddhist terms.** No it wouldn't be nothing there's only change by Buddhist's perspective. It always patient go through such experience cause it affect **mind**. And may you had have depression and when you **finally woke up as a normal man** you was cured. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. It's always pleasurable to tell Dhamma.

Answer (score 0):

> How to describe different stages and passing through different states In my mortal life?

This is most certainly the case with myself. In fact, after 12 months of diligently observing myself, I notice my mind states shift all the time, even from moment to moment. The governor for these shifting states could be our conditioned self. Unfamiliar arising conditions such as the one you describe can allow for a huge shift in consciousness and perhaps one reason for this transition is because they don't conform to our conditioned state, that being: there's no previous blueprint to overlay it with. The self (or conditioned state) has been shook up. My point is, that these changes are occurring all of the time but for the most part they go unnoticed; they are quite subtle. They can indeed be seen as a death and rebirth regardless of their magnitude.

The Tibetan Book of The Dead is an interesting read and can be applied within the finer constituents of life itself. [SEE HERE](https://www.holybooks.com/the-tibetan-book-of-the-dead-2/). Carl Jung has an interesting interpretation of this book.

In a strictly Buddhist sense, one could learn massively from this experience.

> can it be termed as different rebirths(any kind of) for an ordinary man In Buddhist terms.

I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @user 14082 -Thank you for yourValuable  comment.I am a newcomer for this site,so the comment is not easily understandable.It will take time.Thank you -user-26375

Comment: @USER-14082-After experiencing "TRUTH" ,is it his destiny to scientifically return to his old state mysticism[scientifically bound for his previous state}.,giving up" TRUTH" which he found after martyrdom[when he searched FOR the'TRUTH',AND EXPERIENCED IT]  .AFTER LONG YEARS OF MONOTONY,IS IT THAT MYSTICISM GIVES HIM "PEACE" if he can attain it  over again?when he will find  many things mysterious,full of mysteries.again.Can the state  be called "supreme peace".?